# Should hypothetical situations always be written in the past tense?

Tags: tense, imaginary-situations

Example sentence:

> I could follow her to find out what she does, but I risked coming off as a stalker.

I think I heard somewhere that hypothetical situations should always be written in the past tense.

Does this mean writing something like this is wrong?

> I could follow her to find out what she does, but I **risk** coming off as a stalker.

Note: the speaker is speaking in the present tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tenses are not perfectly grammatical.

> I **could follow** her now ... but I **would risk** coming off as a stalker.
>
> I **could have followed** her then ... but I **would have risked** coming off as a stalker.
>
> **If** I followed her now, I **would risk** coming off as a stalker.
>
> If I follow her now, I risk ....
>
> **If** I (had) followed her then, I **(had) risked | would have risked** coming off as a stalker.

Here without the condition:

> I **followed** her then even though I **risked** coming off as a stalker.
>
> I **did follow** her then even though I **risked** coming off as a stalker.
>
> I **am following** her now, even though I **risk** coming off as a stalker.